# How to deploy a Streamlit (frontend) webapp to AWS Lambda using Serverless Framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, streamlit

I have been trying to deploy a streamlit web app to AWS Lambda with serverless framework for quite a few days. I have watched the tutorials and examples on the serverless framework website but none of them talk about deploying frontend in AWS Lambda. The support said that it can be done but not in the usual way it's done in ec2 or some other service.
If anyone has any sources/tutorials that they can point me to, it will help a lot.

Answer (score -1):

What people tend to do is build a frontend using tools like React, Vue, Svelte etc that builds a frontend consisting of only HTML, CSS and JS. The JavaScript talks to your Serverless backend using HTTP requests. The HTML, CSS and JS can then be hosted in an AWS service called S3 and this can be deployed in any number of ways which is probably what the support ( ;) ) meant when they said that.

You could upload the code manually or use a tool you can add to the Serverless Framework called Lift (https://github.com/getlift/lift) which helps make it easier to upload these static files to S3 as a website.